# Azure Event Hubs - custom consumer with SQL checkpoints

Tags: azure, messaging, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

We are currently looking at Azure Event Hubs as a mechanism to dispatch messages to background processors. At the moment the queue-based systems are being used.

Most processors are writing data to SQL Server databases, and the writes are wrapped in transactions.

Event Hubs are positioned as at-least-once communication channel, so duplicate messages should be expected. `EventProcessorHost` is the recommended API on the read side, which automates lease management and checkpointing using Azure Blob Storage.

But we have an idea, for some most critical processors, to implement checkpointing ourselves using a SQL Server table inside the same database, and write the checkpoint inside the same transaction of the processor. This should give us the strong guarantee of exactly once delivery when needed.

Ignoring lease management for now (just run 1 processor per partition), is SQL-based checkpointing a good idea? Are there other drawbacks, except the need to work on lower level of API and handle checkpoints ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage is the built-in solution but we are not limited with that. If most of your processors are writing data to SQL Server databases and you do not want to have EventProcessorHost store checkpoints in Azure Storage (that requires a storage account), in my view, storing checkpoints in your SQL database which provide a easy way to make process event and manage checkpoint transactionally, it would be a good solution.

You could write your own checkpoint manager using [ICheckpointManager interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.icheckpointmanager?view=azureeventhubsprocessor-1.0.1) to storing checkpoints in your SQL database.

Comment: Thank yu Fred. If I implement this interface, will I be able to reuse other parts of EventProcessorHost? Or what's the benefit vs. custom code? Any relevant samples online?

Answer (score 2):

As per Fred's advice, we implemented our own Checkpoint Manager based on a table in SQL Server. You can find the code sample [here](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/mikhailio-samples/blob/master/eventhubs-sqlcheckpoints/SQLCheckpointManager.cs).

This implementation plugs nicely into `EventProcessorHost`. We also had to implement `ILeaseManager`, because they are highly coupled in the default implementation.

In [my blog post](http://mikhail.io/2017/05/reliable-consumer-of-azure-event-hubs/) I've described my motivation for such SQL-based implementation, and the high-level view of the overall solution.

Comment: Great solution. Would you mind sharing some more on how you implemented ILeaseManager? Did you care about workload balancing in the future (as original lease management do)?